# Why is my imageview not changing in android studio app?

Tags: android, android-studio, if-statement

I am creating this app for school project that is supposed to show different icons based on the different Radio Buttons clicked.
So in my layout I have an image View and in my codes I created a switch case to read the radio Buttons clicked. And of course I have an if-else statement underneath that links every Radio Button clicked to unique image that is supposed to appear in a row. However, by default it only executes the else statement, which it the "Others" option. So no matter which button I click, all the options only display the icon for Others. Anybody knows how can I solve this?

Comment: Edit your post and add your code. It's not possible to solve unless we see your code.

Comment: You should put all your radio buttons in a RadioButtonGroup and then fetch that and use "get selected" function to get the id of the selected radio button instead of using a switch case

Comment: @Bruce tysm!! I figured it out :)

Comment: @Omkar76 hey thanks for the input i will do that next time :)